# Replacing Empty String with mode of the column

Tags: python, pandas

I am having the following pandas data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["hitesh","","HAIK"],["hitesh","red","ll"],["haikent","red","tt"],["","","HAIK"]])
```

I am trying to replace the empty strings of the data frame with the corresponding mode of each column.

I am trying

```
df= df.replace("" , df.mode()[0])
```

but this just replaces the 1st column empty string of the data frame with the 1st column mode. Is there a way to replace all the empty strings with their corresponding column mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to replace the empty strings with `NaNs` so that these do not get considered during the `mode` computation. Then, fill these missing elements with the first row of the mode values calculated per column basis.

```
df.replace({"":np.nan}, inplace=True)
df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to_replace
df= df.replace(to_replace=[""], value=df.mode()[0])

Comment: This gave :  0  1  2
0  hitesh  NaN  HAIK
1  hitesh  red  ll
2  haikent  red  tt
3  NaN  NaN  HAIK